# LINQ: Get the path in a hierarchical structure collection item

Tags: c#, linq

How to get the full path of an item in a hierarchical collection using *linq* ??

**Example**:
I have the following type:

```
... item
{
   ... ID ...
   ... Name ...
   ... ParentID ...
}
```

I want to get the path from a specified item iterating through the parents till the root. Similar to the following :

> Root Name / .... / Parent Name / Item Name

Thanx a lot.

Comment: I don't believe LINQ has support for recursive queries, i think you would need several queries to build this up, can't this be build up from the database (if they are represented in the db similarly) Or you can [check this out](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18)

Answer (score 2):

Any specific reason you want to use Linq for this?  This looks like a good place to use regular old recursion:

```
static string GetPath(Item i) {
  if (i.Parent == null)
    return i.Name;
  else
    return GetPath(i.Parent) + "/" + i.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LinqToTree.aspx) is a good article on a technique the author calls LINQ to Tree.

It may not be exactly what you need but it may give you some ideas.

Hope it helps